# I feel Interview day went badly, what could I do to get more chances?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, hiring-process, negotiation, england

Context: I applied to a company and I have real passion and interest to join this company. I am interested in their mission, in the industry, in the position, and I feel myself I am capable of doing a great job. I do prefer companies that follow my passions compared to others (even big ones), and I am aware there are just few of them that are like so. This company is also unique in its own flavour, which makes it my dream company.
This position is a management position in Engineering.
I interviewed yesterday and I finished a whole day of interviews, comprehending 4 stages, 3 behavioural and 1 technical presentation.
I'm scared of a possible No from the company, and I would like that is in my power to proactively increase my chance with real interest.

Previous interview:
previous days I interviewed with the Hiring Manager. The interviews was fine and I was moved to the following one, where I focused on multiple behavioural interviews.

Stages of this interview:

- 1st interview, tech + presentation: I feel it was great, we were both satisfied with questions and answers
- 2nd interview, behavioural product focus: I feel it was ok and I could shine in different aspects, whereas others may have been mediocre/good, I'd say 10% shine, 30% mediocre, 40% good, 20% very good
- 3rd interview, behavioural personal focus: I am very discouraged by my performance in this interview. The person was dead-serious and deep-dived strongly on my answers. I've been asked 3 main questions, the 1st was mainly left 50% unresponded, as I started with a story that the interviewer stopped as being unfitting, asked other questions regarding it, I tried to juggle the situation, but finally, he moved to the next one. The 2nd question was regarding what weakness recently my manager noticed that we're working on and how. This question really hit me strongly, as my manager is the main reason of me changing job, and because I am aware that it is fair to never share any negative fact regarding your current company and manager. I simply do not feel in peace with me to do so. Getting back to the point, my current relationship with my manager is close to none, we do not speak, and when we do it is about status updates. My manager was put as a senior manager of a technical field that she did not grow experience with, and so could not help at all in my technical development. Long story short, I do not have much or any personal sharing with my manager as during our chats we do not talk about it or my improvement. Getting back to the interviewer's questions, at this point, I feel unsafe to say that I am uncomfortable with my manager and that I am not receiving feedback or coaching, and so I thought about responding with something my previous manager mentioned to me and I recognise as a personal weakness: being overly critical with myself. This opened a vortex that spiraled in deep-dived questions that I feel I answered poorly at best. With stops and silence. After this question, I got back on track with my usual energy and happiness, and I could progress greatly with the last half of the interview stage. I feel 60% of this interview went poorly (I would rate myself 2/10), but I feel I could also demonstrate strong care, emotional intelligence and critical thinking in the remaining part for a 10-15%, the rest was acceptable.
- 4th interview came up soon after 3rd, I was vividly sad about how I performed in the 3rd interview, but I feel I could half cope with it by showing a good face and progressing fairly well. I would say this was a 50% good, 20% acceptable, 30% mediocre interview.

Overall, I interviewed with many companies and, from collecting feedback, I don't tend to draw many red flags, but I tend to fail the interview for nervousness, lack of confidence (I'm also not a native speaker), but nothing very big such as arrogance or serial dishonesty. Whereas I have been rated high in my performance plan by my previous managers in my daily and strategical problem-solving skills, I know that I tend to not shine at all when explaining my key results in interviews.

I thought about the following actions or options to take in the close future, but I would appreciate your thoughts on them:

- Add key interviewer(s) to Linkedin, sending a simple thank you for the great experience
- Add key interviewer of 3rd interview to Linkedin, sending a letter of my deep interest and passion and to understand nervousness made me derail from my usual problem-solving attitude and perseverance in getting the best
- Send email to recruiter, with email to send to all my interviewer with thanks, to ask me further questions that I'd be greatly happy to answer any doubts they may have
- Send email to recuirter, with email to only Hiring Manager, saying sincerely how I felt and that I feel in the 3rd interview I could have done better, maybe asking for a second chance
- Send email to recruiter, to ask for a second chance for the 3rd interview or a larger pack, explaining impact caused by nervousness, and high interest in the company.

I would highly appreciate also learning how better these situations could be handled if my options aren't suitable.
Is it reasonable to ask for a second chance (even if I haven't received a feedback yet?)

All in all I'd dream to work for this company and I would like to be proactive in helping to raise my chances, before I'd receive a possible reject.

Also, all in all, I feel I'll get a reject if I do not do anything, based on my experience.

This is my first post in Workplace, and if you feel I should have followed a different approach or supplied more/less information, please do let me know, I'd be happy to correct the trajectory and ask the question in a way that works for the portal and for my own will to get good answers.

Current state: No response received yet, I interviewed Yesterday.

Geographical info: The position is in London, UK, some interviewers are from the States, and specifically, the person that deep-dived in the 3rd interview is from the States.

Many thanks to everybody in advance

Comment: Relax, it's only been one day. You can send a "Thank you" if you want, but don't send anything else. That would only make things worse.

Comment: Can you please try to shorten your post? It's too long.

Comment: Is it about just shortening or better dividing sections? What I mean is, is the message not clear or not given rightly to this audience? How could be better? Many thanks for the help

Comment: Shortening. Try to describe the essentials of a situation at an appropriate level of detail for the audience and what you want from them, both here and in interviews.

Comment: So what was the outcome.  Offer or no-offer?

Comment: no-offer :-( reasons given 1st phase okeish but with doubts, 3rd phase terrible as I described.

Answer (score 8):

You gave it your best shot.  You'll either get the job offer or you won't.  That "thank you note on a stationary" thing they taught in high school isn't as appropriate or useful as it used to be.  Most of the other ideas you have about asking for another chance will not be a good look.

A few things you can do while waiting:

1) Continue on with "plan B" with your career search and keep looking for more interview opportunities elsewhere. No point in waiting by the phone.

2) Reflect on your interview experience. You are correct that you should not speak negatively of your current situation in an interview, but you do need to have positive stories to tell about accomplishments and relationship with your manager. Work on the stories around conflict resolution, self-awareness, ingesting feedback.  These are questions that come up in many interview situations.

3) Share your interview experience and answers with a trusted colleague in your job sector. They will probably give you better advice on what you might have said wrong than this site can.

4) Email the recruiter on Monday with a short note saying you appreciated the interview day and are looking forward to hearing back.  Don't do any more than that.

You get the job - then great.  You'll know you're a good fit from the depth and scrutiny applied in the interview.

You don't get the job - thank the recruiter one more time and leave off with "please consider me for other openings in the future."

Comment: I think this is one truth that I'm struggling to accept as I really would like to do something that could positively impact the situation, given my great interest for the company - And if I had to talk for a friend and not for myself, I feel you are right in thinkin that the best way is looking forward and being proactive in getting on shape and better for the next round.  I would like to give an opportunity to 'positive impactors' though if there are any and persevere in a constructive way

Answer (score 1):

> My manager was put as a senior manager of a technical field that she did not grow experience with, and so could not help at all in my technical development

You seem to misunderstand the role of your manager. Your manager doesn't need to have any experience in the technical field she's managing at all. You are paid to be the specialist in your technical field. Your manager is paid for managing you and your colleagues and for having and setting up the big picture.

It doesn't mean she can't develop you technically. If you feel you need development, ask for it. Be proactive. You say you are applying for jobs as a manager - if you get one, you will be expected to be proactive and drive developments instead of waiting for others to take initiative.

---

Following up can make or break your application. I'm actually convinced that I got my current job because of my individualized, sensible follow-up after a not-so-good interview. But it needs to be done the right way - the individualized way appropriate for the context.

We can't know what you should include. You need to try to understand what your interviewer(s) expected and answer to that.

A generic thank-you note won't cut it in most cases.

Also, the more people the interview was with, the smaller the chance that a follow-up will change anything cause tailoring your message to 4+ people's expectations is difficult.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a comment, I asked for further support and I found outward coaching and pair to be ok, but at the end of the day your manager is your main career impactor. for example my responsibilities were reduced and my manager now does a good part of them. I also tried discus. with my mgr but the reception was counter-productive. I do agree with the fact that I am victimising too, and also that is a difficult situation to handle. Regarding the interview, I spoke to 10 people on the day, maybe an email targeted to the HiringMan only passing through recruiter? what points worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

A thank you note may or may not help, but if you write it well, it can't hurt. Doing the following will maximize your chances:

- **Keep it short.** People are busy, they don't want to read a novel. They shouldn't have to scroll or spend more than a minute reading it.
- **Focus on the positives.** You can't fix anything you did poorly on at this point. Remind them how you did well and why they should want you.
- **Proofread, proofread, proofread.** You don't want any spelling or grammar mistakes or unclear writing. Get someone else to help you if you need to. A poorly written note can cost you a job offer.

In your case, I'd focus on your passion for this specific company, a short description of your most relevant skills and experience, and maybe a mention that your references can attest to those skills.

The person who hired me at my current job five years ago told me he did so because of the thank you note I wrote, so it does sometimes work. Give it a try!